# Template Meta programming - Determining function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

```
template<bool, class T, class U> 
struct IF_ELSE { using type = T; };

template<class T, class U>
struct IF_ELSE<false, T, Y> { using type = U; }

template<class T>
class Object { 

  Object baz(IF_ELSE<boolean_condition<T>::value, foo_class, bar_class>::type param) {

       return Object(param);
   }
};
```

Hello I am trying to create a method that returns an object that is initialized based upon some template conditional. The code above works fine however I would like to use a default constructor (no parameters)

```
template<class T>
class Object { 

  Object baz(IF_ELSE<boolean_condition<T>::value, foo_class, void>::type param) {

       return Object(param);
   }
};
```

However it is not possible to use void as a type (despite `void foo(void);` being a valid decleration)

Is there anyway to do this?

Notes. I DO NOT WANT TO USE TEMPLATE SPECIALIZATION. Although this is a solution for this specific question it would be inconvenient simply use specialization in my current project. Personally I prefer the usage of IF_ELSE opposed to specialization as I find it much more comprehensible.

The only workaround I can think of is something like...

```
template<class T>
class Object { 

  Object baz(IF_ELSE<boolean_condition<T>::value, foo_class, int>::type param = 0) {
        if (param == 0)
       return Object();
        else 
       return Object(param);

   }
};
```

If anyone has a more sophisticated solution that would be great. Much thanks.

----------------------------------EDITED------------------------------

This workaround is a bit nicer (inspired by Oisyn) it more or less combines the best of both worlds of parameter specialization and default parameters. Possibly a bit faster too as it dodges the if statement.

```
template<class T>
class Object
{

public:
struct MAKE_ILLEGAL {};

template<class param>
Object(param p) {/*do stuff */}
Object() {/* default */ }


template<bool b>
Object<T> baz(std::conditional_t<b, int, MAKE_ILLEGAL> param)
{ return Object<T>(param); }

template<bool b>
Object<T> baz(std::conditional_t<b, MAKE_ILLEGAL, int> value = 0)
{ return Object<T>(); }
};

int main() {

    Object<double> obj;
    obj.baz<false>();
}
```

Comment: I don't think there are significantly better options that your workaround (ignoring specializations). Also, your `IF_ELSE` can be replaced with `std::conditional`[`_t`].

Comment: You could make `Object` non-templated and instead do `template <typename ...T> Object baz(T &&... params)`, but I'm not sure it will work with your design.

Comment: Could you do `auto f = []()->void {};` and then instead of `void` pass `decltype(someFunc())` in the template arg

Comment: 1+ for mentioning std::conditional, though I feel like IF_ELSE is more clear about its intentions.

Comment: Then you could create an alias: `template <bool A, typename B, typename C> using IF_ELSE = std::conditional_t<A,B,C>;`. Then you won't need to write `::type` all the time.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well I want to ensure that given some condition that this method must be called with some parameter of some type. using a template pack does not mandate that.

Comment: @JosephFranciscus, The name `conditional` is already established among C++ template metaprogrammers. Using a different name requires anyone reading the code to learn what this is and then realize it's just `std::conditional`.

Comment: @chris I'm a student and the primary language taught is Java so all my C++ is self-taught, so actually didn't know about `std::conditional` in fact I've been using `IF<bool, class>` as my variant for `enable_if` up until a month ago. But yes I most likely switch to conditional once I break my bad habit of IF_ELSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Apparently you're not allowed to use something that resolves to `void` as a function argument in a type-dependent context. I've edited my answer accordingly using a different solution. The original answer can be read below.

```
// A helper that always yields true so we can make the condition type-dependent
// on arbitrary template parameters
template<class T>
constexpr bool true_v = true;

template<class T>
class Object
{
public:
    template<class U = void, std::enable_if_t<Condition<T>::value && true_v<U>, int> = 0>
    Object baz(foo_class param)
    { return Object(param); }

    template<class U = void, std::enable_if_t<!Condition<T>::value && true_v<U>, int> = 0>
    Object baz()
    { return Object(); }
};
```

As long as we're not dealing with special methods like copy/move ctors and copy/move assignment operators (which may not be templatized), we can always apply regular SFINAE tricks. We just need to templatize `baz` using default template arguments, and make sure the condition used for `std::enable_if` is type-dependent on a template parameter of that method (and not solely on `T` in `Object<T>`)

[Live version](https://godbolt.org/g/Rkaqr4)

---

**Original answer**

```
template<class T>
class Object
{
private:
    struct dummy { };

public:
    Object baz(std::conditional_t<Conditional<T>::value, foo_class, dummy> param)
    { return Object(param); }

    Object baz(std::conditional_t<Conditional<T>::value, dummy, void>)
    { return Object(); }
};
```

The idea is that you create both overloads, one for a single parameter and one for none. By selectively replacing the parameter with an inaccessible dummy type, you can make sure you will never be able to call that overload when not appropriate.

Comment: So this does not work because you cannot use void as a type (compile error in both c++14 and c++17)
`invalid parameter type ‘std::conditional_t<false, Object<double>::MAKE_ILLEGAL, void> {aka void}`

but you can do.... (Check edited answer)

Comment: I'll tentatively give you the best answer as I don't think there is an actual solution to this problem and you gave me inspiration for a bit cleaner workaround. (:

Comment: @JosephFranciscus Well, you can, but apparently not in a type-dependent context. So it indeed doesn't work in this case. That's a bummer. But I think I know another trick, I'm fiddling with it now and I'll edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: @JosephFranciscus Yes this works, verified this time ;)